# Change Margins of Navigation Drawer Programmatically

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, margins

I have a navigation drawer, but I want to set some margins, just like setting `android:layout_marginTop="72dp"` in the XML file, but I want to set them programmatically.

My activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:background="@drawable/back_blue_translucent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        tools:context="com.bentleycarr.mentalmaths.MainActivity">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#f9f9f9"/>

        <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginTop="72dp" <!--I want to change this -->
            android:name="com.bentleycarr.mentalmaths.NavigationDrawerFragment" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Above, where it says `android:layout_marginTop="72dp"` - I want to change 'that' to another number in MainActivity.java but I can only find info on how to do this to a LinearLayout or a RelativeLayout etc, not to a `<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"` Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

I tried Aashir's answer but it crashed. Here's the log:
(Ignore this for now - I might have added the wrong ID.)

```
Process: com.bentleycarr.mentalmaths, PID: 23729
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bentleycarr.mentalmaths/com.bentleycarr.mentalmaths.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
        at com.bentleycarr.mentalmaths.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
FrameLayout root = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourID);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)root.getLayoutParams();
   params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom); 
   root.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: It just crashes. :-(
I'll edit the original post, 'cause I can't post logcat in the comments.

Comment: Change FrameLayout to DrawerLayout and add its ID.

Answer (score 0):

I had a task to set margin for exact size from screen border (left/right side), so I overrided default `generateLayoutParams(attrs)` in Drawer Layout to resize its viewPort:

```
public class CustomMarginDrawerLayout extends DrawerLayout {
    private static final int DRAWER_MARGIN_IN_DP = 48;
    private final Context context;

    public CustomMarginDrawerLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public CustomMarginDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public CustomMarginDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewGroup.LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(AttributeSet attrs) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = super.generateLayoutParams(attrs);
        int margin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, DRAWER_MARGIN_IN_DP, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        params.width = getScreenWidth(context) - margin;
        return params;
    }

    private int getScreenWidth(Context context) {
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        return metrics.widthPixels;
    }
}
```